# How to handle paths in PHP for command line scripting (Windows)?

Tags: php, windows

I am using PHP for a command line tool that I am building. My tool has to work both on Windows and *NIX based systems. My primary development environment in Ubuntu Linux.

I was wondering whether I should take care of handling directory separator my self every time I do something with files or would PHP take care or that for me? For example:

In Linux:

```
$user_home = get_user_home_folder();
$filePath = "{$user_home}/path/to/file.txt";
```

Would the code above work on Windows without modification or should I always do something like:

```
$user_home = get_user_home_folder();
$filePath = "{$user_home}/path/to/file.txt";
if(is_windows_os()) {
   $filePath = str_replace('/','\\',$filePath);
}
```

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about the older versions of Windows, but `/` works in Windows 7 and above

Comment: Thank you. you hint helped very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
<?
$filePath = "/path/to/file.txt";

if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    //windows
$filePath = getenv('HOME').str_replace("/", "\\", $filePath);
echo $filePath;
} else {
    //linux
$user_home = get_user_home_folder();
$filePath = $user_home.$filePath;
echo $filePath;
}
?>
```

In my case (windows) outuputs:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\path\to\file.txt
```

**Notes:**
I never heard about a php function called `get_user_home_folder()` I assume it's a custom function.

Comment: get_user_home_folder is a custom function :)

Comment: @gevik you need to check the correct sign in order to mark the answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

This maybe help you.

```
define('DS', is_windows_os() ? '\\' : '/');
$user_home = get_user_home_folder();
$filePath = $user_home.DS."path".DS."to".DS."file.txt"
```

Use constant DS for  path and will be automatically change on need separator

Answer (score 1):

PHP will try to convert '/' to the correct separator when it can.  It also provides a builtin constant called `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` if you don't want to rely on that behaviour.

That constant and the `join` function work well together for building paths.

e.g. `$fullPath = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [$userHome, 'path', 'to', 'file.txt']);`